# Is it possible to run the IIS web server on Linux?

Tags: webserver

Is it possible to install IIS on Linux?

Answer (score 9):

After introducing [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/rhel), now Microsoft officially provide support to run [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/rhel) applications on Linux and you no longer need IIS server to serve .Net applications. You can use [Kestrel web server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x) to server [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/rhel) web applications. A complete guide to serve [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/rhel) web application with Nginx as reverse proxy is given [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x). If you want to use Apache instead of Nginx have a look [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Comment: I understand it's not recommended for production use. And I understand I don't need IIS to run .net apps on Linux. However, for testing purposes I could do withe abiility to run IIS on my Ubuntu.

Comment: Are there open source applications running using this kind of environment? An example would be helpful.

Comment: You can find a lot of opensource projects on following link
https://github.com/thangchung/awesome-dotnet-core

Answer (score 7):

IIS is Microsoft-proprietary web server software that can only run in the Windows operating systems for full support of it and all of its features.  It is not capable of being run in a non-Windows environment without sacrificing some functionality, and you will need Windows Server or Windows 7 with IIS installed on it in order to use IIS and all of its features.

Answer (score 5):

It is not recommended to run IIS in a non-native environment (net exactly sure why you would want to) but it is possible to run .NET applications on Linux.

You should check out `Mono`: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

So the answer is; Yes it is possible but 100% not recommended.
If you would like to run a web server using Linux you should use a native package like `apache`.

Comment: Their message from earlier, before my edits, indicated they want it to run specific MVC software on a web server.  Linux can't run MVC + IIS very efficiently, but the issue here is not that they want to run MVC natively but that they want to run IIS + these MVC apps at the same time, and I'm pretty certain Mono might have issues with that.

Comment: Damn that edit took most the question out then. Also, I just noticed that this is a very old question that you resurrected.

Comment: actually the edit took out the subject.  The subject and the actual content were vastly different, so with the approval of a couple of others, I revised the title to reflect the question in the content.  I can easily revert that and then add to their question, but this is an *old* question that ended up in the suggested edits queue.  (ANd I got a revival badge from it too :P)

Comment: This is what Microsoft uses for their Azure Linux Webapps. `/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe` is the command that's actually running on my webapp right now

Answer (score 0):

As others said, IIS isn't supported on GNU/Linux however, as of (at least) late 2019, you can use the Kestrel web server which runs perfectly fine on Arch, so it shouldn't be a problem to run a .NET Core 3 web server on Ubuntu or any modern distros.

That being said, you should make sure you have the correct .NET Core SDK and runtime (which matches the version specified in your project's `WebApi.csproj` file).